# Unravelling notations in Lean

Tags: lean, lean4

When one is busy writing a proof in Lean, one sometimes encounters symbols, like `+` or `<=`, but one does not know what the underlying function name and instance function name is. How does one go about unfolding a symbol. This is useful if you want to do simp or rw on that function.

Is there a way to use tactics to get the underlying function, for example to know that `+` is, I had to guess to do `rw [HAdd.hAdd]`, I did not find it, I just remembered that H is sometimes prefixed.

Now I can write:

```
theorem nat_add_succ_is_succ_add (n m: Nat):
  succ n + m = succ (n + m) := by
  rw [HAdd.hAdd]
  unfold instHAdd
  simp
  rw [Add.add]
  unfold instAddNat
```

My Tactic state is then

```
nm: Nat
⊢ { add := Nat.add }.1 (succ n) m = succ ({ add := Nat.add }.1 n m)
```

This seems like a long way to go and also I didn't know how to find `HAdd.hAdd`. Is there a more efficient way and how does one go about finding `HAdd.hAdd` or can we skip this altogether using some other command or tactic?

I would also like to unfold my Tactic state to the point that I get:

```
Nat.add (succ n) m = succ (Nat.add n m)
```

But `simp` takes me back to `+`.

Is there a way to bring my Tactic state to this state?

Comment: `simp only` to answer your specific question at the end.

Comment: And usually clicking on things in the tactic state (using widgets) is the quick way to identify what the head symbol actually is.

Comment: related: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/in-lean-how-do-i-expand-a-definition-without-knowing-what-it-is

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know what `+` is short for if you use `simp`.

```
  simp only [(· + ·), Add.add]
  -- new goal: ⊢ Nat.add (succ n) m = succ (Nat.add n m)
```

Here I simply typed out the functions I saw in the info view. I used `simp only` to avoid the global simp lemma `Nat.add_eq`, which as you said would bring us back to `+`.

Now, why does that simp lemma exist? Because we want to make sure that we don't end up with goals using a mixture of abstract `+` and concrete functions like `Nat.add`, which could complicate applying further lemmas to them, i.e. `+` is considered the "canonical form" of `Nat.add`. `Nat.add_succ` is an example of such a lemma stated in terms of `+`, and so we can do the proof without ever unfolding `+`.

```
theorem nat_add_succ_is_succ_add2 (n m : Nat) :
    succ n + m = succ (n + m) := by
  induction m <;> simp_all [Nat.add_succ]
```

This theorem already exists as `Nat.succ_add` by the way.

Comment: `simp only [(· + ·), Add.add]` is pretty great, but how would one do a `rw [(· + ·)]` ?

Comment: `rw` doesn't know about that syntax. It is essentially a dumber `simp`, so it's expected to do less, though whether this particular feature should be supported is a good question.

Comment: I was assuming that the syntax for `(· + ·)` was a general syntax that could be used with rewrite, unfold or anywhere where you would want to reference the `+` function in a tactic.